# pc won't detect lg g3 as an android device

Tags: android, windows, debugging, driver

I'm trying to use my phone to debug apps from Android Studio. However, when I plug my phone in, my pc just detects it as "VS985 4G", and android device monitor doesn't detect it. When I try using "update driver" to install the driver in the ask, it just says that the best driver is already installed and won't let me change it. I already enabled usb debugging on the phone. Does anyone know how I might be able to fix it?

Comment: That's too bad. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: Look, its your mobile/computer issue how does it matter to others if doesn't detect. 

Still if you want an answer- buy a new pc and mobile.
Good Luck

Comment: Having the same issue.  This prevents us from using the phone as a debugging tool in Android Studio.  Not sure why there's so much negativity in the commenters here... the question is clearly stated and the poster is looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message from Windows 7 OS when the device driver was incorrect.  Try playing around until you get one that works.  You didn't say what operating system you are on, but if you have Windows 7:

Start-> Computer -> System Properties -> Device Manager

Select "Android Device" from your list of devices, Right click and select:

Update Driver Software -> Browse My Computer for Driver Software -> Let me Pick From a List of Device Drivers on my Computer ->

Try USB Composite Device if it's an option.

Comment: It doesn't even show up as "Android Device". It just shows up as "VS985 4G".

Comment: Then select VS985 4G.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten that problem before. I have done several different things to fix it. I have unplugged and replugged my phone, then I restarted my phone and restarted android studio. If none of these work, I also opened terminal and typed in:
    killall adb

Once you do that, restart studio and try again. Hope one of these work for you.

Comment: You can also try adb kill-server and then adb start-server